# cert authentication work with signalr in a mixed case

Tags: signalr

I have a hub

Its called by 2 types of clients, browser with identity cookies and c# client with client certs

I can make eitheer work. BUt If I have iis configued to require client certs on /signalr then the browser client connects the user gets prompted for a cert - not good.

I tried

```
var str = String.Format("https://{0}/cert_signalr", url.Host);
    m_hub = new HubConnection(str, false);
```

setting iis to require certs on /cert_signalr and adding a rewrite rule of cert_signalr -> signalr. Didnt work. Seems like the HubConnection paid no attention to me specifying the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code works - what I did wrong was in web config. I needed to have

```
  <location path="cert_signalr">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```